# Using GraphQL to connect to CosmosDB?

Tags: azure, graphql, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a path to follow where you can interface with Azures CosmosDB using GraphQL along with an Azure Functions interface if there needs to be a place where logic is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know CosmoDB at this time only supports these APIs:

- Standard SQL
- MongoDB
- Cassandra
- Azure Table
- Gremlin

If you want to use the GraphQL protocol to query it, you might need to create a wrapper, that translates the GraphQL queries to the appropriate interface.

I would suggest to go for a MongoDB API and implement functions that accept the GraphQL queries and interact with the MongoDB. This should be easy, because MongoDBs queries are looking pretty the same [1].

[1] https://medium.com/the-ideal-system/graphql-and-mongodb-a-quick-example-34643e637e49

Comment: This would be served well as a comment (pointing out that native GraphQL doesn't exist. As for suggesting a particular API: There's simply no way to suggest a particular API without knowing anything about the OP's data modeling needs. And a particular API doesn't limit the use of GraphQL.

Comment: Just added the hint, that using MongoDB and a wrapper would be easy to implement. That wouldn't have worked in a comment...

Comment: The issue with this is, for example with a get query, you still need to pull the full document from the collection and then strip off unwanted fields at the back-end code level. You will still incur latency and RU cost for the entire document json.

Answer (score 5):

I have started on a project [Eklee-Azure-Functions-GraphQl](https://github.com/seekdavidlee/Eklee-Azure-Functions-GraphQl) to implement a GraphQL interface served by Azure HTTP function(s). It currently supports Azure Cosmos DB SQL API. The GraphQL interface is using [graphql-dotnet](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet). It uses a Model-first approach to define and automatically generate your schema. It supports both query and mutation.

Comment: Can you queries for a subset of the things in one SQL "row" with this approach? Does it still pull the full document from the db?

Comment: That's the beauty of GraphQL, you query only for the fields you need and internally, the resolver can understand and craft the right SQL query into Cosmos DB.

Answer (score 0):

I've published a demo of using GraphQL backed by the Azure Cosmos SQL API https://github.com/southpolesteve/graphql-cosmos-demo. It could easily be hosted on Azure Functions